# inserting node at beginning of linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

This program is based on a linked list. It adds the element in the beginning of the list each time `Insert(x)` is called in `main()`. The **big arrow** in the code points to the part I'm not sure I have correct.  My questions are enumerated below:

**Question 1.** The code creates a `global structure pointer head` of type Node and a local pointer to structure `Node` in the `Insert()` function. The first arrow points to code which does `temp->next = head`. Does that mean we are passing in temp->next the address of head or the value inside of head? I guess the value -- please confirm.

Suppose I have case:

```
int a= 2;
int *p;
```

then `p= &a;`
means `p` has the address of `a` but here in code seems like `p=a` i.e. pointer `temp->next = head`

Here the `next pointer= head` means that we are passing the value inside of the head node. If it were the address than we should have used `&head`?

**Question 2.** In the next arrow `head = temp` . I clearly see that we are passing the address of temp to head? Is it correct? Or is it saying the address of temp  to address of temp ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
};
struct Node* head;

void Insert(int x)
{
  struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  temp->data=x;
  temp->next = head;     <------------------------------- (1)
  head= temp;            <------------------------------- (2) 
}

void Print()
{
  struct Node * temp= head;
  printf("List is: ");
  while(temp != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d  ", temp->data);
    temp= temp->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  head =NULL;

  int n, i, x;

  printf("How many Numbers?: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(i= 0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    Insert(x);
    Print();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Q2 : `address of temp` is `&temp`, value of `temp` is return value of `malloc`. `head = temp` : value of `temp` set to value of `head`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your first question:**

You declare a pointer called head:

```
struct Node* head;
```

The pointer is an address that points to a value in the memory.
When you do:

```
temp->next = head;
```

Then you assign the pointer **head** to **temp->next**. So it's not the value of head, but the address that points to the value.

**You second question:**

You first declare a pointer temp and you allocate some memory for it:

```
struct Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Then you assign it to head (the head pointer now points to the temp allocated memory):

```
head= temp;
```

Both are pointers, so you save the **temp** pointer in the **head** pointer. Nothing more. For example:
Lets say your **head** pointer points to address 0001. And your **temp** pointer points to address 0002. If you do **head = temp**, then **head** will point to address 0002.

Example:

```
struct Node node1;
```

node1 is not a pointer, so it has the value. If you want to make a pointer out of the value then you need to take the address of node1:

```
struct Node *node1Pointer = &node1;
```

The **&node1** means, the **address of node1**.

if now you want the value of **node1** and get it from **node1Pointer** then you have to dereference it:

```
struct Node node2 = *node1Pointer;
```

The ***nodePointer** means, give me the value to which this pointer points to.

Now lets assume you have node1 that has a pointer **node1Pointer** with address 0001. And you have another node, **node2** that has a **node2Pointer** that points to address 0002.

Consider the following:

```
 struct Node *tempNodePointer = node2Pointer;
```

**tempNodePointer** points to address 0002

```
 node2Pointer = node1Pointer;
```

**node2Pointer** now points to address 0001

```
 node1Pointer = 0;
```

**node1Pointer** now points to nothing, nullpointer

```
 struct Node nodeValue = *node2Pointer;
```

**nodeValue** now has the value that was stored at address 0001

```
 node1Pointer = &nodeValue;
```

**node1Pointer** now points to address 0001

This will probably clarify a little better.

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: can you please explain last line of your answer `Both are pointers, so you save the temp pointer in the head pointer. Nothing more.`  so does that means now every thing we had in temp pointer is been copied to head? So where is the allocated temp gone?

Comment: No, you only copy the address. So its like saying that head gets a new address. But i will try to clarify it with an example.

Comment: but the i you first answer temp->next is also a pointer to structure Node? Aren't we copying head pointer into temp->next ?

Comment: @Noobsplzdon't-1 does that clarify your doubts?

Comment: @fonZ Don't keep adding that cast back. It's harmful.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant i didnt do anything. Besides the question is not about casting ... i just copy pasted his code to make him understand how pointers work, cast has nothing to do with that. And even if it is harmful, it's off topic here. Furthermore, your edits have to be approved by mods i think.

Answer (score 1):

your code has a lot of bugs. While working with linked lists,you need to have a START pointer that stores the address of the first node of your list else you won't be able to access the list. As you keep adding nodes to your list,the head node traverses to your last node and it cannot be taken as your starting node. And the answers for your question is already given by @fonZ . I'll suggest you the following code for creating and inserting nodes in a linked list.

```
void create()
{
    int term,i;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("\nEnter the data : ");
        scanf("%d",&temp->data);
        temp->next=0;
        if(start==0)
        {
            start=temp;
            curr=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            curr->next=temp;
            curr=temp;
        }
        printf("Do you want to create another node?y\\n.. ");
        ch=getche();
    }while(ch!='n');
} 
void insert(int pos,int val)
{
    int count=1;
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next=0;
    temp->data=val;
    if(pos==1)
    {
        if(start==0)
            start=temp;
        else
        {
            temp->next=start;
            start=temp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        curr=start;
        while(count!=pos)
        {
            prev=curr;
            curr=curr->next;
            count++;
        }
        temp->next=prev->next;
        prev->next=temp;
    }
}
```